# VueJs Custom currency mask

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My Currency mask has got some issues.

When I am typing say `10000` in the field, it formats it as expected `10,000` but the moment i shift focus to another field or press tab. The mask shifts the comma position to the left by 1. i.e. `10,000` becomes `1,0000`

You can check codepan for the issue, can anyone help me with this?

https://codepen.io/veer3383/pen/BxqzLb?editors=1010#

The template:

`<v-text-field @keyup="formatCurrency(initialBalance, $event)" :prefix="currency" v-model="initialBalance" label="Balance" :disabled="disabled"></v-text-field>`

The method:

```
formatCurrency (num: any, e: any) {
    num = num + '';
    var number = num.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
    var splitArray = number.split('.');
    var integer = splitArray[0];
    var mantissa = splitArray.length > 1 ? '.' + splitArray[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(integer)){
        integer = integer.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    e.currentTarget.value = integer + mantissa.substring(0, 3);
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a `keyup` AND `v-model`, they may end up creating a conflict. I find it's easier to use a computed value (or a watch with a formatted version).

template:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
    <v-flex lg3="">
      <v-text-field :prefix="currency" v-model="initialBalanceFormatted" label="Balance" :disabled="disabled"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

script:

```
function formatAsCurrency (value, dec) {
  dec = dec || 0
  if (value === null) {
    return 0
  }
  return '' + value.toFixed(dec).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    disabled: false,
    currency: "£",
    initialBalance: null,
  }),

  computed: {
    initialBalanceFormatted: {
      get: function() {
        return formatAsCurrency(this.initialBalance, 0)
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.initialBalance =  Number(newValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It helps to turn these inputs into separate (reusable) components if you have more than one or two.

Here's an example I made a while back that uses components that can handle other types like percentage, does formatting only after blured (so your comma is not jumping) and allows to use up and down key for increment/decrement

https://codepen.io/scorch/pen/oZLLbv?editors=1010

Comment: that's what the code does, the link at the end is shown as an example for putting it into reusable components

Comment: The codepen now gives a warning when updating any formatted values: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.

Comment: yes, the reason it gives that warning is that it's not a good practice to mutate the props. You can swith to use `vue.min.js` instead of `vue.js` if you just want the warning to go away. But it's better practice to create an internal data variable to track the internal value changes. This isn't likely to cause issues in this instance, but it is good to adhere to such vue guidlines.

Comment: I've updated that example  to use internal value (`_value`)