# How to add data mask in an <input v-model=variable> and not using npm

Tags: html, vue.js, cdn, v-model, data-masking

I can get salary data from my database using vue js v-model like this

[image]

but i want to add data mask to look like this

[image]

here is my code for my retrieve, the field key salary / gaji is a double, i dont know how to add data mask using vue js, can anyone help me??

```
<div class="form-row">

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">

         <label class="col-form-label">Salary</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="nasabah.form.salary">

      </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJs Custom currency mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373777/vuejs-custom-currency-mask)

Comment: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask This one works fine in vue js without npm package.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help : [v-mask package](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-v-mask-when-building-forms-with-vue-js-62b774d4b927)

Comment: i'm not using npm

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `computed` to format the displayed value in the input.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rawSalary: 0
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
    this.rawSalary = e.target.value;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formattedSalary() {
      return this.rawSalary.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>Salary</label>
  <input type="text" :value="formattedSalary" @change="onChange">
  
  <div>rawSalary : {{ rawSalary }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the v-model ?

Comment: You react to the changes manually via `@change` event.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `filter` to format the number into currency, for example:

```
filters: {
  currencyFormat(val) {
    return (val).toFixed(2)
              .replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
  }
}
```

Use pipes to use it on your template, for example:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="nasabah.form.salary | formatCurrency">
</div>
```

Please note that this will mutate your `salary` property with the formatted value

You can learn more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)